# Intent shows extras as null, but then when emulator reloads after error is accepted its shows values

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

On running the below code, a RunTime exception is thrown with a NumberFormatException: Invalid long : "null". But when ok is clicked on the emulator error, the activity is reloaded with the correct values from the intent.

Intent being sent:

```
public void onLogEnd(){
        //Location location;
        x = 0;
        double avgSpeed = getSpeed(mFirstLocation, mLastLocation);
        avgSpeedKm = (distance(mLastLocation, mFirstLocation) / (mLastLocation.getTime() - this.mFirstLocation.getTime()));
        Log.d("avg speed=", "" + avgSpeed);
        Log.d("avg speedKm=", "" + avgSpeedKm);

        Float distance = mFirstLocation.distanceTo(mLastLocation);
        Log.d("distanceto", distance.toString());

        Long time  = mLastLocation.getTime() - mFirstLocation.getTime();
        String time1 = time.toString();
        Log.d("time", time1);



        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(MyBoundService.this, ViewSessionDataActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        i.putExtra("DISTANCE", convertDistance(distance));
        Log.d("distance string", convertDistance(distance));
        Log.d("time string", time1);
        i.putExtra("TIME", time1);

        i.putExtra("SPEED", formatSpeed(avgSpeed));
        startActivity(i);


    }
```

Logs shown from above:

```
01-10 14:07:55.478 2719-2719/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/avg speed=: 
37.658861226881335
01-10 14:07:55.478 2719-2719/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/avg speedKm=: 
0.037658861226881335
01-10 14:07:55.479 2719-2719/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/distanceto: 
377.8733
01-10 14:07:55.479 2719-2719/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/time: 10000
01-10 14:07:55.479 2719-2719/com.example.tristanokeefe.running 
D/distance string: 0.38
01-10 14:07:55.479 2719-2719/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/time string: 
10000
```

Receiving onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_session_data);
    Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy 'at' hh:mm aaa");

    this.distance_view = findViewById(R.id.distance);
    this.speed_view = findViewById(R.id.speed);
    this.time_view = findViewById(R.id.time);
    this.save_button = findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    this.delete_button = findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

    this.date = new Date();

    //getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
    //        MyProviderContractOverall.ALL_URI, true, new ViewSessionDataActivity.MyObserver(new Handler()));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    distance = intent.getStringExtra("DISTANCE");
    String time = intent.getStringExtra("TIME");
    speed = intent.getStringExtra("SPEED");
    Log.d("distance =", "" + distance);
    Log.d("time1 =", "" + time);
    Log.d("speed =", "" + speed);
    final long time1 = Long.parseLong(time);
    //final long time1 = 10000;
    final String date = dateFormat.format(currentTime);



    Log.d("distance","" + distance);
    Log.d("time","" + time1);
    Log.d("speed","" + speed);
    Log.d("time", "" + date);
    distance_view.setText(distance + "Km");
    speed_view.setText(speed + "m/s");
    time_view.setText(getDurationBreakdown(time1));
```

Error printout:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tristanokeefe.running/com.example.tristanokeefe.running.Activity.ViewSessionDataActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
                                                                                   at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:321)
                                                                                   at com.example.tristanokeefe.running.Activity.ViewSessionDataActivity.onCreate(ViewSessionDataActivity.java:69)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The error is being called on the line final Long time = Long.parseLong(time1)
and the printout of the log's testing the intent's received is:

`01-10 13:53:03.189 26552-26552/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/distance =: null
01-10 13:53:03.189 26552-26552/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/time1 =: null
01-10 13:53:03.189 26552-26552/com.example.tristanokeefe.running D/speed =: null`

I have tried sending it as a bundle but that is also showing null on receipt of the intent. 
Link to project:
[Project](https://github.com/okeetris/Running)

Answer (score 1):

Your `mLastLastLocation` is null by the time you start activity.. just after getting `mLastLocation` use `startActivity(i);` or just add a null checking before converting `String` to `Long`

```
if(time1 !=null && time1!="" && time1!=" ")
  final long time1 = Long.parseLong(time);
```

Comment: If my 'mLastLocation' was null surely i wouldn't be able to calculate the values shown in outputted in the logs?

Comment: share the link of the project